# On change form get value and set as session variable

Tags: php, jquery, session, post, session-variables

I am having this form:

```
<form id="sessie_datum" method="post">
<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Klik hier om een datum te kiezen" name="wapbk_hidden_date" value="">
</form>
```

I want to get the value on change the date in the datepicker. I get this with:

```
$("form#sessie_datum").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/datum.php',
                data: $("form#sessie_datum").serialize(),
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function() {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            });
});
```

It gives me a `Success alert` but what do I need to do now in my `datum.php` file to set the value in a `session` variable?

datum.php file is like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

    $_SESSION["datum"] = $_POST["wapbk_hidden_date"];  
    echo $_SESSION["datum"];

?>
```

Comment: Well, you need to actually _write_ some PHP code.  Do you have any?  If not, now would be the time to write some.  If you _do_, you should show it in your question.  A basic search will show you how to use sessions.

Comment: Ummm. Do you have any idea on how to solve this from what else you are learning?

Comment: I edit my question but when doing this nothing is shown if I open the `datum.php` file

Comment: one simple `if(isset($_POST["wapbk_hidden_date"]))` in your `datum.php` will save you lot of time.

Comment: As you are using ajax call ,so whatever you will `echo` in your php  file will send back as a response in your `success function` .Now to check if value is set or not just add `success: function(data) { alert(data); // to show value }` .

Comment: Why and how will my code be look like then?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " if I open the datum.php file"?  How are you going about doing that?  Navigating to that page directly in a new window?  Because that will obviously overwrite the session value.

Comment: _“nothing is shown if I open the datum.php file”_ - you mean, when you call that script _directly_ in your browser, by typing the URL into the address bar? Well then `$_POST["wapbk_hidden_date"]` will obviously not be set, so you are writing an empty string into your session variable, and your debug output of that value will probably be pretty much invisible then …

Comment: if I `success: function(data) {alert(data);}` I get nothing

Comment: Then use your browser dev tools, network panel, to check what the request actually gets answered with.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a short working example, based on your code:

**HTML** (datum.html):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <form id="sessie_datum" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Klik hier om een datum te kiezen" name="wapbk_hidden_date" value="">
        </form>
        <script>
            $("#datepicker").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'datum.php',
                    data: $("#sessie_datum").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success!');
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log('error!');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP** (datum.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'])){
        $_SESSION['datum'] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['datum']) && strlen($_SESSION['datum']) > 0){
        echo $_SESSION['datum'];
    }else{
        echo 'No datum yet defined.';
    }
?>
```

Console output:

```
datum.html:17 success!
datum.html:18 This string is coming from the HTML input.
```

Place both files in a same folder on your web server and observe the console when you are performing changes in the input field (on blur).

Comment: Thanks man, this works. Only looks like a plugin is messing things up. If I disable the plugin and change the value of the field I get a success function  and the session variable is set. If I enable the plugin I get a success function with the right data but opening `datum.php` still says 'No datum yet defined.' pretty weird.

Comment: @LTCode, as you probably know, `session_start()` must be called before outputting any HTML, so most probably your plugin causes HTML output before your script runs.

Comment: Ok, how can I check this?

Comment: you can add `die()` in `datum.php` right before `$_SESSION['datum'] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];` and to observe is there any HTML output into the dev console.